# Use MongoDB with Symfony 4

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, symfony4

I've a some little problems with **Symfony 4** and MongoDB Atlas (cloud cluster... but in local i think it's the same). I'm on Windows 10 pro with php 7.1.1.

Based on this article

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

this is the code inside my admin controller

```
 $mongo = new MongoClient();
        $dbs = $mongo->listDBs();
        print_r($dbs);
```

i receive this error

```
Attempted to load class "MongoClient" from namespace "App\Controller\Admin".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "MongoClient"?
```

but: my extension is loaded correctly.

**MongoDb ext. phpinfo() output**

```
mongodb
MongoDB support enabled
MongoDB extension version   1.3.4
MongoDB extension stability     stable
libbson bundled version     1.8.2
libmongoc bundled version   1.8.2
libmongoc SSL   enabled
libmongoc SSL library   OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto    enabled
libmongoc crypto library    libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile     disabled
libmongoc SASL  enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mongodb.debug   no value
```

**composer.json**

```
"alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.1",
"doctrine/mongodb": "^1.6",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.2",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.4",
"mongodb/mongodb": "^1.2",
```

**Composer Version**

```
1.6
```

I also use mongodb-odm-bundle. This work fine, but i'd like to use also official legacy mongodb lib in my projects (connection with cluster it's ok). But when i try to use MongoClient() i get this error...

so, which "use statement" i must to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct configuration for Symfony 4 + Mongodb Atlas

1) composer require mongodb/mongodb (nothing else)

CONTROLLER

```
namespace App\Controller\your_controller;
```

INCLUDE LIBRARY

```
use MongoDB;
```

CONNECTION (for example get the databases list)

```
$connection = 'mongodb://___full_URI_MongoDBAtlas___';
$client = new MongoDB\Client($connection);
$dbs = $client->listDatabases();
var_dump($dbs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Clients class name (I think you meant `mongodb/mongodb`, not from `doctrine/mongodb`) is: `\MongoDB\Client`.

So updating your code should do the trick:

```
$mongo = new \MongoDB\Client();
$dbs = $mongo->listDBs();
print_r($dbs);
```

Comment: hi michael. With "\" in \MongoDB give an error. without not.

$mongo = new MongoDB\Client(); i think it's correct. but executing this line output is a white page (not error). No listdb given... Yes: i mean mongodb/mongodb...

Comment: i'd like to use connection setuo that i use in .env (like in mongoOdmBundle), without repeating anytime the string connection. Something like this
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager(); where doctrine_mongodb is my symfony connection setup

Comment: Which error? Blank page indicates a (silenced) Fatal Error (class not found?).

Comment: with $mongo = new MongoDB\Client() it's ok. the problem now is another. 
With $dbs = $mongo->listDatabases(); no results. i read this http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

Comment: Ahh okay, you should be able to ask your manager to get the Mongo connection like this: `$this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()->getConnection()->getMongo();`

Comment: `$connection = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()->getConnection(‌​)->getMongo();
  $mongo = new MongoDB\Client($connection);
  $dbs = $mongo->listDatabases();
  print_r($dbs);` error. Notice: Use of undefined constant ‌​ - assumed '‌​'

Comment: the error is in this line `$connection = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')`...